# Setting up ethereum transactions within a cloud function or AWS Lambda function?

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, smart-contract-wallets, sendsignedtransaction

I'm wondering if somebody has figured out how to transact on the blockchain via google cloud functions, or perhaps AWS Lambda?

I am able to write web apps in Angular with leverage ether.js and the metamask wallet for a browser, but I'm unclear about how to set up a cloud function for calling contract functions from a priviged (secure) environment where you can't have a wallet like metamask signing transactions for you.  I thought I could establish (somehow) an ethers.js JsonRPCSigner, but not clear from the documentation how you provide the private keys so that the cloud function can intiate transfers and the like.   Are the examples out there I can look at?

Any guidance appreciated.